# Spring boot SQL script manually

Tags: java, sql, spring, database, spring-boot

I got a task, to create a basic app with some database handling.
I'm really new at this, the whole spring boot and stuff.
I did all the GET, PUT, POST, DELETE stuff without writing any line of SQL, starts with table creation.
But they asked me to provide the SQL script, how I managed to create the database structure, connections and stuff.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you've already got the database working ... without SQL.  But now you've been asked to generate SQL (for what's already working).  Correct?  SOLUTION: Just configure Spring/JPA to dump the SQL commands (e.g. on a scratch database), and copy/paste the output from the Spring boot log into a SQL script: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to spring.jpa.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-source=metadata
```

Please refer this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema by @baeldung for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can used Jpa  Like JpaRepository interface. You don't need write any SQL query we use it just used config your data base into `Application.Property` like database type

Your user name and password

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

when execute this code you can used create user , get find all user , find user by id , delete user and update user

and used @Entity annotaion into Entity class
the Entity class Represent Table into your database

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User{
@Colume(name="id")
private Long id;
@Colume(name="name")
private String name;

//getter and setter here
}
```

when run this class your data base contract User table with id and
name

this link create spring boot application with database
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Comment: That's how I did it. But they asked me to provide the SQL script in a separate .sql file

Comment: the hibernate in your system record any operation between db and your app but i dont know where you can find this record or 
if you can write this logger into text file or not but you can search it  @Artisz

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to do this is to create in the `resources` folder a file named `schema.sql` with all your queries concerning the DDL (tables creation...) and a `data.sql` if needed where you can add `INSERT` queries to populate your database.

In the application.properties then you have to add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to disable the schema creation of JPA and let Spring Boot executes those scripts at startup automatically.

If you want something more powerful, you should try [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) or [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).